# Word Ribbon Command Interception

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, ms-office, add-in

Hello  StackOverflowers,

I'm having the following ribbon xml code in a Word Addin (VS 2012/.NET 4.5):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" >

  <commands>
    <!-- Working commands -->
    <command idMso="ReviewTrackChanges"  onAction="onMsoToggleCommand"/>
    <command idMso="SmartArtInsert" onAction="onMsoCommand"/>
    <command idMso="Thesaurus" onAction="onMsoCommand"/>

    <!-- NOT Working commands -->
    <command idMso="MailMergeStartLetters" onAction="onMsoToggleCommand"/>
    <command idMso="MailMergeStartEmail" onAction="onMsoToggleCommand"/>
    <command idMso="MailMergeStartEnvelopes" onAction="onMsoToggleCommand"/>
    <command idMso="MailMergeStartLabels" onAction="onMsoToggleCommand"/>
    <command idMso="MailMergeStartDirectory" onAction="onMsoToggleCommand"/>
    <!-- NOT Working commands as well?!-->
    <command idMso="ReviewCompareTwoVersions" onAction="onMsoCommand"/>
    <command idMso="ReviewCombineRevisions" onAction="onMsoCommand"/>
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

The corresponding callbacks are:

```
public void onMsoToggleCommand(IRibbonControl control, bool pressed, ref bool cancelDefault)
{
   cancelDefault = false;
   Logger.LogEvent(control.Id);
}
```

And:

```
public void onMsoCommand(IRibbonControl control, ref bool Cancel)
{
   Cancel = false;
   Logger.LogEvent(control.Id);
}
```

I want to intercept these commands to make extra tasks. For Word 2010 and 2013 everything is working as expected, however, for Word 2007 ONLY the first 3 commands seem to be working, Any suggestions on what could be the reason?

Attaching the two groups of commands I'm trying to intercept:

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Do you get any UI errors in Word? See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @Eugene Astafiev for your suggestion, the tip does really helps me finding what's going wrong. You saved my future when pointing me to "Showing Add-in UI Errors", Thanks a lot :) I will write the answer explaining how did I solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Eugene Astafiev's comment, I was finally able to solve this issue. In fact, the original XML ribbon code was something like this (notice the presence of some Excel commands in the middle):

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" >
  <commands>
    <!-- Working Word commands -->
    <command idMso="ReviewTrackChanges"  onAction="onMsoToggleCommand"/>
    <command idMso="SmartArtInsert" onAction="onMsoCommand"/>
    <command idMso="Thesaurus" onAction="onMsoCommand"/>

    <!-- Excel Commands -->
    <command idMso="Connections" onAction="onMsoCommand"/>
    <command idMso="Refresh" onAction="onMsoCommand"/>
    <command idMso="RefreshAll" onAction="onMsoCommand"/>

    <!-- NOT Working Word commands -->
    <command idMso="MailMergeStartLetters" onAction="onMsoToggleCommand"/>
    <command idMso="MailMergeStartEmail" onAction="onMsoToggleCommand"/>
    <!-- Remaining Word commands.. -->
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

So, when Word 2007 try to read this XML, it encounters Excel commands and since it does not recognize them, it simply ignores them with the rest of the XML, hence the rest of Word commands do not get called! For Word 2010 and 2013 it was working just perfect.
I ended up by separating Word and Excel ribbon commands into two xml files then load the correct one based on the Office app.